# Find the volume of the solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lies above the $xy$-plane,inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2= 2$ and below the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I first need to setup my double integral to represent the volume as specified in the question. I am having a hard time figuring out how i should even approach this question. I know the latter is an elliptic paraboloid, thus intuitively it makes sense that it opens up on the $z$ -axis within the cylinder and intersects the edges of the cylinder when $z=2$. With that being said I am having a hard time  figuring out how to sketch this on the $xy$ plane in order to determine the setup for the double integration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The volume of the solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lies above the $xy$-plane, inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and below ANY graph $z=f(x,y)\geq 0$ is given by
$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}f(x,y)\,dx dy=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^R f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\,r dr d\theta$$
where at the second step we used the [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes i understand now, my lecture did not reach the polar coordinate section yet so it was a bit harder to conceptualize just using rectangular. Thanks!